# Fahrenheit To Celsius Converter in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, converters

I'm trying to write a program in vb where a user is asked to type in a value in either the Fahrenheit Textbox or the Celsius Textbox.  I want to use just **ONE** button to perform the calculations and two textboxes to display the outputs but I'm not sure I understand what's happening. The number I type into the Textbox isn't what's been calculated.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub convertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles convertButton.Click

    Dim FahrenheitValue, CelsiusValue As Double

    FahrenheitValue = Val(fahrenheitBox.Text)
    CelsiusValue = Val(celsiusBox.Text)

        FahrenheitValue = (9 / 5) * (CelsiusValue + 32)
        CelsiusValue = (5 / 9) * (FahrenheitValue - 32)

        celsiusBox.Text = CelsiusValue
        fahrenheitBox.Text = FahrenheitValue


End Sub
```

I'm trying my best not to create different buttons for the calculations. How do I make the Boxes accept and calculate the right values typed into the box?

Comment: Entering the title of your question in Google returns lots of usable suggestions. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: Yeah, but all of them involve using more than one button on the form to perform the calculation.

Comment: you need *something* to divine the users intention either 2 buttons, a combo or radio button.

Comment: This just went wrong because you didn't think about the user interface of your program.  Which textbox is the user supposed to type the number into?  Your code just assumed both and that of course does not work.  Use a textbox, a radiobutton that selects the conversion, a label to display the result.

Comment: You are reading the text from both text boxes, doing your calculations then updating **both textboxes**. There is so much potential for interference if the initial values in the boxes are not already an exact conversion. You need to make sure that when the user enter text in a box, your program **clear the other box**. Then you do your calculations based on this single value (you need to detect from which box) and can update the result in the other box.

Comment: You will want to check if one of the text boxes is blank and compute based on the value in the other. If both are blank do nothing. If both are filled that is an error. Although this won't solve your problems I'll point out the calculation is wrong for fahrenheit. Should be something like ((9/5)*cels)+32 . Notice how the +32 is added after the other calculation. You add 32 to cels and then multiply by 5/9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One major problem is here:

```
FahrenheitValue = (9 / 5) * (CelsiusValue + 32)
CelsiusValue = (5 / 9) * (FahrenheitValue - 32)
```

Aside from the math being a little bit off you're changing the value right before using it again.

I.E. I enter 0 in celsius:

- FV = (9/5) * 0 + 32

FV now equals 32

- CV = (5/9) * 32 - 32 == -14.22

Try This:

```
      Dim ResultFV As Double = (CelsiusValue * (5 / 9) + 32)
      Dim ResultCV As Double = (FahrenheitValue - 32) * (9 / 5)
```

Additionally it would be smart to clear the textbox values after you take them.

**Edit**

The other comments are also correct that an additional problem is you're not setting which computation needs to be done.

Try:

```
Public Class Form1
     Dim celsiusActive As Boolean


     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
          Dim FahrenheitValue As Double = 0
          Dim CelsiusValue As Double = 0

          FahrenheitValue = Val(fahrenheitBox.Text)
          CelsiusValue = Val(celsiusBox.Text)

          Dim ResultFV As Double = (CelsiusValue * (5 / 9) + 32)
          Dim ResultCV As Double = (FahrenheitValue - 32) * (9 / 5)


          If celsiusActive Then
               fahrenheitBox.Text = ResultFV
          Else
               celsiusBox.Text = ResultCV
          End If

     End Sub

     Private Sub celsiusBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles celsiusBox.TextChanged
          celsiusActive = True
     End Sub

     Private Sub fahrenheitBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles fahrenheitBox.TextChanged
          celsiusActive = False
     End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand it correctly, the celsius value would be nothing if the user enters the value in the Fahrenheit textbox. That way, your FahrenheitValue will always be calculated as (9/5)*(0+32). If it's the other way around, it should work.
I think you would need an check where the user entered the value and depending on that, you perform the corresponding calculation.

The code would be sth like this:

```
if fahrenheitBox.Text IS Nothing then
CelsiusValue = Val(celsiusBox.Text)
FahrenheitValue = (9 / 5) * (CelsiusValue + 32)

else
die
```